# EJS Relative Path "include" Issue in HTML File

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I have a problem with my "index.ejs" file...

The current content of the ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <!-- THIS SECTION IS FOR <head> TAG THAT WILL BE STORED INSIDE "so_head-tag.ejs" -->
  <%- include('/home/username/Desktop/www/website.com/views/partials/so_head-tag.ejs') %>

<body>

  <!-- THIS SECTION IS FOR NAVIGATION BAR THAT WILL BE STORED INSIDE "so_header.ejs" -->
  <%- include('/home/username/Desktop/www/website.com/views/partials/so_header.ejs') %>

  <div class="filler">

  </div>

  <!-- THIS SECTION IS FOR FOOTER BAR THAT WILL BE STORED INSIDE "so_footer.ejs" -->
  <%- include('/home/username/Desktop/www/website.com/views/partials/so_footer.ejs') %>

  <!-- THIS SECTION IS FOR JAVASCRIPT FILES THAT WILL BE STORED INSIDE "so_javacript.ejs" -->
  <%- include('/home/username/Desktop/www/website.com/views/partials/so_javacript.ejs') %>

</body>

</html>
```

In the current configuration, the pages are rendered perfectly. The only problem in here is though, we give absolute path. So when I try to copy files to a new server, because the username may be different, I have to manually change those usernames into the every server I copy these files. I would like to use some kind of a relative path method.

Current placements of the files are like this:

[image]

I am really stuck at giving relative path as it throws error as soon as I use this in ejs file:

> <%-
> include(__dirname + '/views/partials/so_footer.ejs')
> %>

Reference error:

dirname is not defined.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

To include a sub-template file, you need to provide the relative path from the parent template to the sub-template.

For example, from `pages/index.ejs`, to include `partials/so_head-tag.ejs`, you can use:

```
 <%- include('../partials/so_head-tag.ejs') %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly!